# Can you please check my proof about this function?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I defined $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as 
$$ f(x) = x^2 \chi_{\mathbb Q}(x) $$

Then I claim it is not differentiable anywhere on $\mathbb R$ except at $0$. Please can you check my proof?

Firstly, $f$ is differentiable at $0$:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}{f(x) - f(0) \over x} = \lim_{x \to 0}{x^2 \chi_{\mathbb Q}(x) \over x} = \lim_{x \to 0}x \chi_{\mathbb Q}(x) = 0$$

But $f$ is not differentiable anywhere else because $f$ is not continuous at any point other than $0$.

Comment: What does mean by $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$?

Comment: Your proof is very good, but depending on the context of this exercise you might still have to prove that $f$ is not continuous at any other point. @Lion: It's the characteristic function of the rationals.

Comment: @TooOldForMath:Thank you very much!

Comment: @TooOldForMath Thank you very much for your comment. Good point. But it's obvious to me (let $x$ be away from zero more than $K$ then show $f$ is discontinuous at $x$ should work). So I will be satisfied with my proof for now.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone pushes you to provide a proof of the discontinuity claim, you can write: for every $x\in\mathbb R$
$$\limsup_{y\to x} \chi_{\mathbb Q}(y)=1,\qquad \liminf_{y\to x} \chi_{\mathbb Q}(y)=0$$
Hence, 
$$\limsup_{y\to x} f(y)=x^2,\qquad \liminf_{y\to x} f(y)=0$$
which proves discontinuity for all $x\ne0$.

The differentiability proof is correct, as previously said.